# Jquery UI isn't loading in ASP.NET page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, loading

I'm trying to assign the Jquery datepicker to an aspx page, but no matter how hard I try the Jquery just doesn't seem to load. This is my pages code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title> Movie Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; line-height: -1; font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT', Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif;}
        body {background: white url('bg.jpg') top left repeat-x;}
        h1 {color: white; margin-bottom: 8px;}
        #wrapper {margin: 0 auto; width: 450px;}
        #content {margin: 100px 0 20px 0; padding: 40px 20px; border: 10px solid white; width: 380px; background: #4ec0e5;background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%, #3296b6 100%);background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#4ec0e5), color-stop(100%,#3296b6));background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%,#3296b6 100%);background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%,#3296b6 100%);background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%,#3296b6 100%);background: linear-gradient(top, #4ec0e5 0%,#3296b6 100%);filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4ec0e5', endColorstr='#3296b6',GradientType=0 );-moz-border-radius: 52px;border-radius: 52px;}
        .rqd {color: #f00;}
        #buttons{margin-top: 20px;text-align: center;}
        #submit, #reset {-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');background-color:#ededed;-moz-border-radius:6px;-webkit-border-radius:6px;border-radius:6px;border:1px solid #dcdcdc;display:inline-block;color:#777777;padding:6px 24px;text-decoration:none;text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;}
        #submit:hover, #reset:hover {background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');background-color:#dfdfdf;}
        #ValidationSummary1 ul{list-style: none; margin: 10px 0 0 10px; font-size: smaller;color: white;}
        #ValidationSummary1 li{border-bottom: 1px solid red;}
        #resultLbl{margin: 10px 0 0 10px; font-size: smaller;color: white;}
    </style>
    <!--[if gte IE 9]>
      <style type="text/css">
        .gradient {
           filter: none;
        }
      </style>
    <![endif]-->    
        <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />   
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content" class="gradient">
            <h1>Movie <strong>Form</strong></h1>
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" Width="380px">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Width="45%">
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="fNameLbl" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="fName" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="fNameRqd" ControlToValidate="fName" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your first name'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your first name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="fNameReg" ControlToValidate="fName" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,40}$"  Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your name can be no more than 40 characters'>" ErrorMessage="Your name can be no more than 40 characters"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="address1lbl" runat="server" Text="Address Line 1"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="address1" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="address1Rqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="address1" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your address'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your address"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="address1Reg" ControlToValidate="address1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,120}$"  Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your address can be no more than 120 characters'>" ErrorMessage="Your address can be no more than 120 characters"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="townlbl" runat="server" Text="Town/City"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="town" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="townRqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="town" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your Town/City'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Town/City"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="townReg" ControlToValidate="town" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,76}$"  Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your Town/City name can be no more than 76 characters'>" ErrorMessage="Your Town/City name can be no more than 76 characters"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="postcodelbl" runat="server" Text="Postcode"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="postcode" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="postcodeRqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="postcode" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your Postcode'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Postcode"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="postcodeReg" runat="server" ControlToValidate="postcode" ValidationExpression="\d{4}" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your Postcode can only be 4 digits long'>" ErrorMessage="Your Postcode can only be 4 digits long"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="emaillbl" runat="server" Text="Email"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="emailRqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your email'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your email"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="emailReg" runat="server" ControlToValidate="email" ValidationExpression="^(?=.{0,100}$)\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$"  Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter a valid email address less than 100 characters long'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid email address less than 100 characters long"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="phonelbl" runat="server" Text="Phone No."></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="phone" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="phoneReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="phone" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your phone number'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your phone number"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="phoneReg" runat="server" ControlToValidate="phone" ValidationExpression="\d{0,14}" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Your phone number can be no longer than 14 digits'>" ErrorMessage="Your phone number can be no longer than 14 digits"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="doblbl" runat="server" Text="D.O.B"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<span style="font-style: italic; font-size: x-small;">(dd/mm/yyy)</span>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="dob" runat="server" Width="140px" CssClass="datePicker"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="dobRqd" runat="server" ControlToValidate="dob" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter your Date of Birth'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Date of Birth"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CompareValidator id="dateValidator" runat="server" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ControlToValidate="dob" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyy'>" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date in the format dd/mm/yyy"></asp:CompareValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="movielbl" runat="server" Text="Favourite Move"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="movie" runat="server" Width="140px">
                            <asp:ListItem>We Bought a Zoo</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>The Breakfast Club</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Puss in Boots</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="movieReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="movie" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please pick a movie'>" ErrorMessage="Please pick a movie"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <span class="rqd">*</span>&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="genderlbl" runat="server" Text="Gender"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="gender" runat="server" Width="140px">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="male">Male</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="female">Female</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="genderReq" runat="server" ControlToValidate="gender" Text="&nbsp;<img src='err.png' alt='*' title='Please pick a gender'>" ErrorMessage="Please pick a gender"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table> 
            <div id="buttons">
                <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" />&nbsp;<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" id="reset" />
            </div>
            <asp:Label ID="resultLbl" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>    
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $(".datePicker").datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            });
        })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CS File

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            resultLbl.Text = "Congratulations this is valid data!";
        }
    }
}
```

All the files are right, they are all there, it just won't show. Any ideas?

I also tried the id in the script at the bottom as #<%= dob.ClientID  %> as some people suggested but it just will not load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried declaring the jquery script reference first?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Update! As I said in the comments below, I got it working, just had to remove the line:

```
showOn: "button"
```

[image: Working]

Comment: +1 for this, nice spot! All jQuery plugins, including jQuery UI, require the jQuery JS file to be included before them. My guess is this should do the trick.

Comment: There is a property you have set on the datepicker:
showOn: "button"
Try removing that, and then clicking in the textbox.  It worked for me with your code (and with the reordering of the script files of course).

Comment: Tried re-ordering the scripts and still won't load. Have updated my code above. Thanks so far

Comment: I updated my original answer,  it even works with the ShowButton value, however since I don't have the calendar graphic, it was hard to find the right spot to click on. Other than the script files being reversed, your code is fine.

Comment: hmm. I've got it the exact same and it STILL doesn't work. This is really odd. Even tried in Firefox.

Comment: I would try posting a live version but I currently only own linux hosting

Comment: This is my cs file

`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            resultLbl.Text = "Congratulations this is valid data!";
        }
    }
}`

Comment: When I do a preview this is the code that comes up. (Sorry ran out of room on original post) http://pastebin.com/Ye5L6hfH

Comment: Are you seeing the calendar button next to the date show up for you at all?  In the html code that you posted, it works fine as long as you have a "calendar.gif" file in the correct location (the root directory). If the "calendar.gif" file is not there, than the button doesn't show at all, and can't be clicked.

Comment: the line that the image is referenced in your code is: 
buttonImage: "calendar.gif"  Are you saying that this line shouldn't be there?

Comment: Oh no that should be there. It's just not showing on the page. I've just realized I've been coding this in Visual Studio 11. When I debug it came up with no errors. I've just redone it in VS10 and it came up with 13 errors which I've fixed, but now I get a "Function expected" error on the Javascript on the bottom.

Comment: Ok it seems it doesn't like these both together

`{
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
            }`

It only likes if I just do the calender or just do the month view.

Comment: Ok I got it all to work, Thanks @Javram. My only problem now is when I try to select a date I get the error: error: length is null or not an object. I found a fix at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datepicker/issues/detail?id=56 but can't work out where I add in the extra parts changeMonth: true, changeYear: true. Can you help with this or do I need to start another question?

Comment: Glad to help,  nice to hear that you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you posted the entirety of your code, I can think of 2 things:

1. You seem to have not referenced the CSS file for jQuery UI.  It is required and should have been part of your downloaded package.  The default name for you should be similar to `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css`.  Keep in mind the css also refers to a number of static resources that need to be in the correct locations relative to the css file.  The jQuery UI [Getting Started Guide](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started) has all the information you need to set up jQuery UI correctly.
2. Since you seem to have downloaded a custom build of jQuery UI, did you remeber to include the DatePicker widget?

Comment: Hey yea tried both these but still doesn't seem to work. It's as though something is blocking it.

Answer (score -1):

The script statement at the bottom may need another set of parenthesis to actually run the function. Right now it is declared but not being run.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datePicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: The `$(function() { ... });` syntax is jQuery shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`, and should work fine.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry, missed the $. Thanks.